# Asymptotic behavior of a monotone function

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $f:(0,1)\to(0,1)$ is a monotonically increasing function with $f(0)=0$. No further smoothness of $f$ is known. Assume there exists a sequence $(x_{k})_{k}$ with $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k=0$, such that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{f(x_k)}{f(2 x_k)}\,= 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Is it possible to derive any estimate for $f$ close to $x=0$?

Answer (score 3):

Because $f(x_k)/f(2x_k) \to 0$ you can find $n$ such that $f(x_k)/f(2x_k) < \frac{1}{2}$ for all $k \geqslant n$.  Now select a subsequence $\{\xi_j\}$ of the $\{x_k\}$ as follows:

1. define $\xi_0 = x_n$;
2. for each $j > 0$ choose $n_j > n_{j-1}$ such that $x_{n_j} < \frac{1}{2} \xi_{j-1}$, possible because the $x_k$ tend to zero, and then define $\xi_j = x_{n_j}$.

We thus have a subsequence, also approaching zero, in which $\xi_n < \frac{1}{2} \xi_{n-1}$ and for all $\xi_n$, $f(\xi_n) < \frac{1}{2}f(2\xi_n)$.  It then follows, by induction if need be, that $f(\xi_n) < 2^{-n} f(\xi_0)$.

This is enough to show that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$.  For any $\varepsilon$ we can find $n$ such that $2^{-n}f(\xi_0) < \varepsilon$ and so for all $x < \xi_n$, because $f$ is monotonically increasing,
$$ 0 < f(x) < f(\xi_n) < 2^{-n}f(\xi_0) < \varepsilon$$

Comment: Many thanks for the nice argument. I am wondering if a pointwise estimate like $f(x_k)\leq c exp(-1/x_k)$ is possible?

Comment: I am not sure that it can be guaranteed.  Consider $x_k=1/\log k$ and $f(x) = \exp(-1/\sqrt x)$.  I think you have $f(x)/f(2x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$.    But $f(x_k)=\exp(-\sqrt{\log k})$, which does  not meet your criteria.  I've not worked this carefully, so errors and omissions may exist.